# Auto close sidebar navigation menu when you click on menu item bootsrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I'm making a sidebar menu with a close button in it. But I'm trying to implement some codes that allow the sidebar menu to be automatically close when you click on a menu item.

this is a snippet of the sidebar menu code and i try to implement a onclick on the menu item with a function of closeNav()

Here is the javascript that i want to implement. What did i do wrong here? and is there a better way to do it with or without using javascript?

```js
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "0%";
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Sidebar Holder -->
  <nav id="sidebar">
    <div id="dismiss">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <h3>Tutorial OnPay</h3>
    </div>

    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
      <p>Topik 1 : Pendaftaran + Pengaktifan + Log Masuk</p>
      <li>
        <a href="#daftar" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">1.1 Pendaftaran OnPay</a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="daftar">
          <li><a href="#section1" onclick="closeNav()">1.1.1 Layari Laman Web</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">1.1.2 Pilih Subdomain</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">1.1.3 Pilih Emel</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section4">1.1.4 Pilih ID dan Kata Laluan</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section5">1.1.5 Isi Maklumat Profil Diri</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section6">1.1.6 Pengesahan Spam/Robot (reCAPTCHA)</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section7">1.1.7 Klik Butang Daftar</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#aktif" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">1.2 Pengaktifan Akaun</a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="aktif">
          <li><a href="#section8">1.2.1 Semak Emel "Pendaftaran Akaun OnPay"</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section9">1.2.2 Tekan Hyperlink Pengaktifan Akaun</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section10">1.2.3 Pengaktifan Akaun Berjaya</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#logmasuk" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">1.3 Log Masuk Akaun OnPay</a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="logmasuk">
          <li><a href="#section11">1.3.1 Layari Halaman Log Masuk Akaun Anda</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section12">1.3.2 Masukkan ID Admin dan Kata Laluan</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section13">1.3.3 Log Masuk OnPay Berjaya</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried
document.getElementById("sidebar").style.display = "none";

Answer (score 0):

I would recomment to wrap your code into an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```
(function () {
    // get sidebar element
    var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');

    function closeNav() {
        sidebar.style.width = "0%";
    }

    // get all `a` tags inside sidebar
    var aTags = sidebar.getElementsByTagName('a');

    // for each tag
    aTags.forEach(function (a) {
        // add click event listener to execute closeNav on `click`
        a.addEventListener('click', closeNav);
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alif

I came up with this solution:

```
function closeNav() {
    $('#sidebar .collapse li a').on('click', function() {
        $('#sidebar [data-toggle="collapse"]').collapse('hide')
        $('#sidebar').hide()
    })
}
```

It listens on list item link clicks and then collapses lists inside it and hides the sidebar.

Note: As You are using bootstrap i'm guessing You can use JQuery as this example requires jQuery.

Comment: Thats a good idea tho. My example was taken from a website that has that kind of function and i was experimenting with it. I thought if i could manupulated with its width that it will close. I will try your suggestion tho. thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the style.width. Try using css property 'visibility'

```
 <script>

function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("sidebar").style.visibility= "hidden";
}
</script>
```

I think even then it won't free up the space occupied by that element. Another approach could be z-index.

But easiest and the cleanest is to use the remove() function. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

```
<script>

    function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("sidebar").remove();
    }
    </script>
```

And when you need it create it dynamically using the appendChild method.

Comment: Thats a good idea tho. My example was taken from a website that has that kind of function and i was experimenting with it. I thought if i could manupulated with its width that it will close. I will try your suggestion tho. thanks for the solution

Comment: You're answer for using the remove() function works, but then i stumbble upon that this button cannot be click after i run the function                                                                                       
 <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></i>
                                <span>Tutorial OnPay</span>
                            </button>